# Stop flv looping

Tags: flash, loops, flv

I have a video player swf which loads in a flv file via flashvars. This works perfectly, but when it reaches the end it loops ie Goes back to start and plays again. This only happens when it is embedded in a page because when I press cntl+Enter to preview as swf alone it works.

It's loaded via netstream. Here's the last bit of code...

```
var isPlaying:Boolean;
isPlaying = false;

var video:String;
video = _root.videoURL;


if (video == undefined) {
    video = "http://www.masterseries.co.uk/public/TempFiles/Concrete1.flv";
}


function playVideo() {
    isPlaying = true;
    trace("Play Video...");
    _root.myvid_mc.ns.play(video);
    _root.cover_mc.play_btn._visible = false;
}
```

Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: What video player are you using? Some component or the flex one?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FLVPlayer, have you tried doing this?

```
if (Math.round(flvPlayer.playheadTime) == Math.round(flvPlayer.totalTime)) {
        flvPlayer.stop();
}
```

Comment: The swf seems to work when by itself but when in page it doesn't so not actually the flash code. Do flv's loop by default?

Comment: No it shouldn't if you're using the FLVPlayback component.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head; if you are using the FLVPlayback or any of its derived classes, it should not loop at all by default. However, you might be getting a suppressed runtime error; possibly some security sandbox violation which disrupts the proper execution of the code. In any case you might try:

```
player.autoRewind = true;
```

Where `player` is the name of your playback component.